# Is there an efficient generalized algorithm to find at least one binary word with the maximum rotational imbalance and the full $\{0, 1\}$-balance?

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, combinatorics-on-words

Assuming that $x$ is a sequence of $l$ bits (i.e. a binary word of length $l$) and $0 \le m < l$, let $R(x, m)$ denote the result of the left bitwise rotation (i.e. the left [circular shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift)) of $x$ by $m$ bits. For example, if $x = 0100110001110000$, then $l = 16$ and $$\begin{array}{l}
R(x,0) = x = {\rm{0100110001110000}},\\
R(x,1) = {\rm{1001100011100000}},\\
R(x,2) = {\rm{0011000111000001}},\\
 \ldots \\
R(x,15) = {\rm{0010011000111000}}.
\end{array}$$

Let $A \oplus B$ denote the result of the bitwise [“exclusive or”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation for two sequences of $l$ bits. For example, $$0100110001110000 \oplus 1010010001000010 = 1110100000110010.$$

Let $H(x)$ denote the number of non-zero bits in $x$ (i.e. the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of $x$).

Assuming that $x$ is an $l$-bit word, let $f(x)$ denote the minimal element (the smallest number) in the tuple $$\begin{array}{l}
(H(x \oplus R(x, 1)),\\
H(x \oplus R(x, 2)),\\
 \ldots, \\
H(x \oplus R(x, l - 2)),\\
H(x \oplus R(x, l - 1))).
\end{array}$$

For example, $$\begin{array}{l}
f(10011110100010010011) = 10,\\ 
f(11111111111111111111111111111111) = 0,\\
f(10000000000000000000000000000000) = 2,\\
f(10011100001111100000011111110000) = 8,\\
f(01000110111111100011100100100101) = 16.
\end{array}$$

Question: assuming that for any even natural number $n \ge 2$ there exists a $2n$-bit word $x$ such that $f(x) = n$ and $H(x) = n$, what can be a *time- and space-efficient* algorithm which, given an arbitrary (even) $n \ge 2$, allows to find *at least one* such $x$? For example, if $n = 10$, it is easy to check all $20$-bit words and find (in the lexicographic order) $$\begin{array}{l}
x_0 = 00000101011011001111,\\ 
x_1 = 00000101011110011011,\\
x_2 = 00000101101110011101,\\
x_3 = 00000101110011101101,\\
\ldots,\\
x_{718} = 11111010100001100100,\\
x_{719} = 11111010100100110000.
\end{array}$$

But as the value of $n$ grows, it becomes infeasible to check the huge amount of elements, even if one skips any element $x$ such that $H(x) \neq n$. For example, how can one find a $256$-bit word $x$ such that $f(x) = H(x) = 128$?

Let $S_n (n = 2, 4, 6, \ldots)$ denote cardinality of the set of solutions for the corresponding $n$. Note that each solution $x$ is an element of the *family* of solutions, and this family contains exactly $2n$ elements, namely, $x$ and $(2n-1)$ its rotations. So we can pick a single (e.g. lexicographically first) element of a family and call it a *canonical solution* (all other elements of the corresponding family can be generated from this solution in a trivial way). Then let $C_n (n = 2, 4, 6, \ldots)$ denote cardinality of the set of canonical solutions for the corresponding $n$. If my computations are correct, we have

$$\begin{array}{l}
S_2 = 4 = 2^2,\\
C_2 = 1 = 2^0,\\
S_4 = 48 = 2^5 + 2^4,\\
C_4 = 6 = 2^2 + 2^1,\\
S_6 = 144 = 2^7 + 2^4,\\
C_6 = 12 = 2^3 + 2^2,\\
S_8 = 768 = 2^9 + 2^8,\\
C_8 = 48 = 2^5 + 2^4,\\
S_{10} = 720 = 2^9 + 2^7 + 2^6 + 2^4,\\
C_{10} = 36 = 2^5 + 2^2,\\
S_{12} = 5376 = 2^{12} + 2^{10} + 2^8,\\
C_{12} = 224 = 2^7 + 2^6 + 2^5,\\
S_{14} = 3360 = 2^{11} + 2^{10} + 2^8 + 2^5,\\
C_{14} = 120 = 2^6 + 2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3,\\
S_{16} = 4096 = 2^{12},\\
C_{16} = 128 = 2^7.
\end{array}$$

Interestingly, six of the first eight elements of the tuple $(C_2, C_4, \ldots)$ are [highly composite numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number): $1, 6, 12, 48, 36, 120$. I cannot explain the fact that $S_{16}$ and $C_{16}$ are powers of two, but it does not look like a random coincidence.

Comment: Isn't f(10000000000000000000000000000000)=2?

Comment: This can be rephrased as a question in additive combinatorics: you want a set of $n$ elements from $\mathbb{Z}/2n\mathbb{Z}$ such that the multiset of the $n(n-1)$ non-trivial differences has no element occurring more than $\frac n2$ times.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: $n=3$ is odd, but I already specified that $n$ must be even.

Comment: Here's the lexicographically least example for $n=18$: 000000010011101011001101011110010111

Comment: Results for $n\in\{2,\dots,15\}$ yield a maximum of $2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

Comment: @RobPratt for $n=17$ that can also be achieved by 0000000001110011011010110111010111.

Comment: I concur with your calculations and can add $S_{18} = 9504$. I note that the proportion of balanced words with the desired property is decreasing, so sample-and-reject is not going to scale effectively. And as a minor comment (which has, however, not helped me in literature searches), wlog the canonical element can be taken to be a Lyndon word.

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to prove that solutions, in fact, _exist_ for _all_ even $n$. Is there anything that allows us to exclude the possibility that the number of solutions drops to $0$ for some $n$?

Comment: The notion of family can be extended with other transformations such as inversion of all bits, and reading words backwards.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I think there are a couple of reasons to prefer the definition of family given here: for one it only uses the symmetry operation (cyclic shift) under consideration and not the full symmetry group accessible; for another, the possible fixed points of your transformations make the counting more difficult and might mean that your corresponding $C_n$ doesn't evenly divide $S_n$. (It's straightforward to show that $f(x)=0$ for any periodic word and so for any word that meets OP's condition its cyclic shifts are distinct.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function $f(x)$ is closely related to the notion of *autocorrelation*, which for a binary sequence $x$ of length $|x|=N$ and shift $w$ can be expressed as
$$\textbf{AC}_x(w) := N - 2H(x\oplus R(x,w)).$$
The values of $\textbf{AC}_x(w)$ for various non-trivial shifts (i.e. $1\leq w\leq N-1$) are called *out-of-phase autocorrelation values*.

So,
$$f(x) = \min_{1\leq w\leq N-1} H(x\oplus R(x,w)) = \frac{N}2 - \frac12\max_{1\leq w\leq N-1} \textbf{AC}_x(w).$$

For the known constructions for optimal binary sequence w.r.t. autocorrelation, I refer to the paper [Cai and Ding (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2009.02.021).

In particular, for $N=q-1\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, where $q$ is a power of prime, the Sidelnikov–Lempel–Cohn–Eastman construction produces a sequence $x$ with $H(x)=\frac{N}2$ and out-of-phase autocorrelation values $\{0,-4\}$, thus giving $f(x)=\frac{N}2$ as requested in the question. The value $N=256$ well fits into this construction since $q=257$ is prime. Here is one such 256-bit word:

```
0011101101010000101000110101100110101001111011001111111100011111010110011111100000100000011011001011011001110001000001000011110100001011010001010001001001100011110011100101011101011010100110000010100100101010110011101001111110011000001101111101000000111011
```

Answer (score -2):

Suppose x contains n 1’s, and y is a cyclic shift of x. Suppose that there are exactly m positions where both x and y have 1’s. Then x XOR y has 2(n-m) 1’s. Thus f(x) is always even. Thus a necessary condition for H(x) = f(x) = n is that n is even.

Consider the length 4 sequence x = 0110. The cyclic shifts are
x_1=1100, and
x_2=1001, and
x_3 = 0011, so that
x XOR x_1 =  2, and
x XOR x_2 = 4, and
x XOR x_3 = 2.
Thus f(x) = 2.

Now consider a sequence y = (0110)^m =0110 0110 ... (m times) … 0110. The cyclic shifts of y are
y_1=(1100)^m
y_2=(1001)^m, and
x_3 = (0011)^m, so that
y XOR y_1 =  2m
y XOR y_2 = 4m
y XOR y_3 = 2m.
Thus f(y) = 2m =H(y).

This gives explicit solutions to f(x)= H(x) wherever solutions exist.

Comment: You've failed to take into account shifting $y$ by $4$ when $m > 1$, so that $f(y) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. My bad!