# Two questions about three circulant matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, circulant-matrices

Consider the following matrix equation in $n \times n$ [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) $\pm 1$ matrices $A$, $B$, $C$

$$2AA^T+BB^T+CC^T=(4n+4)I-4J$$

where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix and $J$ is the $n×n$ matrix of ones. My questions:

1. Are all orders good? Here the term "good" means that the equation has at least one solution.
2. How to find $A$, $B$ and $C$ when $n$ is given?

Any comment/answer would be appreciated.

---

**Related**

- [One question on circulant $\pm1$ matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/q/434368)

Comment: If $n+1$ is the order of a Hadamard matrix, then normalising and removing the row and column of all-ones gives a matrix such that $MM^{\top} = (n+1)I - J$. Taking $A, B, C$ all equal to $M$ gives a solution. For question (2) the techniques used for finding Williamson matrices could probably be adapted to find solutions computationally.

Comment: Have you tried writing the $\binom{n+1}{2}$ equations in $3n$ binary unknowns for, say, $n=3$?

Comment: I have tried $n=3$, $M=A=B=C=\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -1 & 1\\
        1 & -1 & -1 \\
        -1  & 1 & -1
      \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: I meant using $3$ unknowns per matrix.

Comment: You have $\binom{n+1}{2}$ equations in $3n$ binary unknowns. For $n=3$, you have $6$ equations in $9$ binary unknowns.  For $n=4$, you have $10$ equations in $12$ binary unknowns.  For $n=5$, you have $15$ equations in $15$ binary unknowns.  What about for $n=6$? Do you get the idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I got it right. Your idea is brute force searching the $3n$ binary unknowns. Maybe there are some better methods I don't know.

Comment: The number of unknowns grows linearly with $n$, whereas the number of equations grows quadratically with $n$. You go from underdetermined to overdetermined. It's not about brute force. Rather, it's about paying attention to what the Gramians look like. For example, since the entries on the main diagonal of the Gramians are all $n$, there are actually only $\binom{n}{2}$ equations

Comment: For what it worth, in terms of accompanying polynomials of circulants $A, B, C$, the equation reads as $2 a(x)a(1/x)+b(x)b(1/x)+c(x)c(1/x)\equiv 4n+4-4(1+x+...+x^{n-1})\pmod {x^n-1}$, where $a, b, c$ are polynomials of degree $n-1$ with coefficients $\pm 1$.

Comment: From the linked question, you can see that if you take $A$, $B$ $C$ to be circulant matrices with maximal-length sequences as their first row this gives an infinite set of solutions for when $n=2^k-1,k\geq 2.$